# problems with a filter date in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, date

i have a problems with my filter date , I would like to filter between 2 date but with a condition if the date `from` is not valid then I start at `2017-01-01` (for that I think it is good) and if the date 'to' is not valid I start Has the current date

Here is my plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/8sK29zG7YoPOdntbFfcK?p=preview

Thank you for your help

Comment: Post the relevant code in your question, tell what it's supposed to do and what it does instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter could be something like this :

```
app.filter("myfilter", function($filter) {

      return function(items, from, to) {

      const testFrom = Date.parse(from);
      const testTo = Date.parse(to);      


      if (!testFrom){
        console.log('Not valid');
        from = moment('2017-01-01');
      }

      //here it does nt work
      if (!testTo){
       to = moment();              
      }      


      const valids = items.reduce((acc,val) => {
         const date = moment(val.dateenvoi);
         if(date.isSameOrAfter(from) && date.isSameOrBefore(to))
          acc.push(val)        
        return acc;
      },[]);      
      return valids;      
      };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

No need for custom filter for this functionality, you can use angular predefined filter for this like

```
<input type="text" name="S_Date" ng-model="filter.dateenvoi"/>
```

and

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in myData | filter: filter">
```

working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RyFXROT3vvLqUA8ug1kH?p=preview)